# [UIImageView _isChargeEnabled]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, crash, mpmoviewcontroller

I am getting this error message from an apparently private API. Anyone have a clue what this could be? It seems to occur, if you use MPMoviePlayerViewController and do a pinch while the movie is running. This will close the player, but afterwards the app crashes.

Only seems to be a problem with certain version of iOS (in this case iOS 3.2.2 on an iPad).

I found o[ne post in another forum](http://markmail.org/message/ezhwvhtihqwtmnn5), but that did not really help, as with MPMoviePlayerController [a different problem occurs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206147/avplaybackitem-fpitem-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance)

Comment: Did you find an explanation for this?

Comment: No, I did not. I ended up (as far as I can remember) implementing two versions. One that used MPMoviePlayerViewController and one that used MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the issue is not the private API, it's that you've got a zombie object.